# bootstrap css conditional equal statement for mobile

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using jumbotron in a row of three columns with same height for my web site. This work perfectly instead of mobile. Responsiveness is not working because of the 'equal' class that fix the height of the box to the higher content.

```
<div class="row equal">
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">test 1</div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">test 1</div>
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">test 1</div>
</div>
```

I see a solution by making 'equal' to be conditional to the size of the media but i don't know how to do and I'm not sure it is the best way  ?

Maybe somebody may help a little bit ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you create a demo of the issue?

Comment: www.projet-okinawa.ch, home page, the jumbotron (2 rows, 6 jumbotron)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just define a `@media` query for this class. Like this -

```
@media all and (min-width:768px){
    .equal{
        background: #CCC; 
        /* or property which should be applied when your screen width is 768px or above */
    }
}
```

One thing you've to keep in mind, this works only if other property is also set by a class selector. If you use `id` (like `#red`, `#blue`,  `#green` instead of `.red`, `.blue`,  `.green`) then you need to apply the `!important` specificity ( `id` > `.class` )

**[Simple example](http://jsfiddle.net/avwv3p0a/)** - just resize the result window

Comment: This is great to change, override or add something, I just want to call or not depending on the size, is it  the way also ?

Comment: I would say yes, if you use CSS only.